# Porque no realiza la suma mi ciclo for

Tags: java

Hola a todos estoy estudiando un curso de Java pero no puedo entender porque el resultado de Sum es 0

```
public class TestClass{
 public static void main (String args []){
  int sum = 0;
   for (int i = 0, j = 10; sum > 20; ++i, --j)
   {
     sum = sum+ i + j; //1
   }
   System.out.println("Sum = " + sum);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para entender el comportamiento de tu código, primero hay que repasar un poco más a fondo el funcionamiento del **for**:

Dentro de los controles de flujo provistos por Java, encontramos el **for**, que se caracteriza por creado de bucles en nuestro código, es decir, darnos la capacidad de ejecutar las mismas lineas de código cantas veces queramos (o mejor dicho que la condición de parada nos permita).

A continuación se detallará una forma de utilizarlo, quizás la más "sencilla" o al menos la que servirá de referencia:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Podemos ahondar en 3 elementos importantes:

1. Bloque de declaración/inicialización: se ejecuta al principio del for y por **única** vez. Es usual declarar e inicializar variables de control.
2. Bloque de control: Se ejecuta **cada vez** que se quiere ingresar a un bucle y si la condición es verdadera ejecuta lo que hay dentro del for; de lo contrario saltea todo el bloque. Es usual comprar la variable de control.
3. Bloque de ejecución al final de la iteración: una vez terminada cada la iteración, se ejecuta **cada vez** el código que se coloque alli, es usual incrementar o decrementar una variable de control.

En tu caso particular no se realiza ninguna entrada al for, debido a que la condición es inicialmente falsa.

Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias tu respuesta ha sido de gran ayuda

Answer (score 1):

La condición de finalización del bucle for es incorrecta.

Debería ser suma < 20

Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Revisa la condición de tu ciclo for.
Como lo tienes ahora, no se repetirá porque sum es 0 y la iteración será mientras sum sea mayor a 20.